# How pass variable in url to ng-repeat?

Tags: arrays, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

How to use ng-repeat with the variable in the url? My url is like this: `#/timeline/{{year}}/{{month}}`

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
       <li ng-repeat="months in dateMonths"><a href="#/timeline/{{months}}">{{months}}</a></li>
</ul>
```

And the array in scope:

```
$scope.dateMonths = {2014: ['jun', 'jul', 'aug', 'sep', 'nov', 'dec']}, {2013: ['jan', 'feb', 'apr', 'oct']};
```

If I put the year within the array called functions normally

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
       <li ng-repeat="months in dateMonths.2014"><a href="#/timeline/{{months}}">{{months}}</a></li>
</ul>
```

But I wanted something, for example:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
       <li ng-repeat="months in dateMonths.{{year}}"><a href="#/timeline/{{months}}">{{months}}</a></li>
</ul>
```

What to do?

Comment: Did you try `months in dateMonths[year]` ? Also consider using `ng-href`

Comment: What about dateMonths['{{year}}'] ?

Comment: @Avraam That wont work. You do not have to do that. The expression will be evaluated against the scope anyways. `months in dateMonths[year]` is just enough. http://jsbin.com/lupotufiqo/2/edit

Comment: Are you able to put the entire variable in an array?

Comment: Also note that the dateMonths object in the question has syntax error. Working demo is here http://jsbin.com/lupotufiqo/2/edit

Comment: @PSL @Avraam thanks! It worked perfectly. Funny that I previously tried with `months in dateMonths.year` and did not work.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this for one of the objects:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
   <div ng-repeat="(year, months) in dateMonths">
   <li ng-repeat="month in months"><a href="#/timeline/{{month}}">{{month}}</a></li>
   </div>
</ul>
```

However if you want to ng-repeat over all the objects, you either need a variable for every object, or you need to create an array of objects. If you decide to create an array of objects, you could do this:

```
<ul role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
   <div ng-repeat="(object, year) in dateMonths">
      <div ng-repeat="(year, months) in year">
      {{year}}
       <li ng-repeat="month in months"><a href="#/timeline/{{month}}">{{month}}</a></li>
      </div>
   </div>
</ul>
```

where

```
  $scope.dateMonths = [{2014: ['jun', 'jul', 'aug', 'sep', 'nov', 'dec']}, {2013: ['jan', 'feb', 'apr', 'oct']}];
```